# GraphQL Custom directive enforcing value restrictions

Tags: neo4j, graphql, next.js

I need to create a custom directive on INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION to check if the provided value of the enum isn't being changed to the previous "state" (business logic is that states must go UNAPPROVED - > APPROVED -> CANCELLED -> FULFILLED) but can't quite figure out how to map values in constructor of the enum type.

All my code is available at [github](https://github.com/pmakowski23/AJI/tree/master/Exercise_4)

I'm using nextJs backend functionality with neo4j database that generates resolvers for whole schema.

```js
// order Schema

export const order = gql`
  type Order {
    id: ID! @id
    state: OrderState!
    user: User! @relationship(type: "MADE", direction: IN)
    createdAt: DateTime! @timestamp(operations: [CREATE])
    products: [Product!] @relationship(type: "INCLUDE", direction: OUT)
  }

  enum OrderState {
    UNAPPROVED
    APPROVED
    CANCELLED
    FULFILLED
  }
`;

export const extendOrder = gql`
  extend input OrderCreateInput {
    state: OrderState!
  }
`;
```

I want to create `@checkState` directive that would check if the updating `state` is valid

I used as a base example from [GraphQL Tools docs](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/schema-directives#enforcing-value-restrictions) but it's with string values. I would much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using custom directive I used `graphql-middleware` lib to create middleware that is triggered only when updateOrders mutation is being used.

```js
Middleware

import { ValidationError } from "apollo-server-micro";
import { IMiddleware } from "graphql-middleware";
import { Order } from "pages/api/graphql";

export const checkStateMiddleware: IMiddleware = {
  Mutation: {
    updateOrders: async (resolve, parent, args, ctx, info) => {
      const { where, update } = args;

      const [existing] = await Order.find({
        ...where,
      });

      const states = ["UNAPPROVED", "APPROVED", "CANCELLED", "FULLFIELD"];

      const currentState = states.indexOf(existing.state);
      const toBeUpdatedState = states.indexOf(update.state);

      if (toBeUpdatedState < currentState) {
        throw new ValidationError("Can't update value with previous state.");
      }

      return resolve(parent, args);
    },
  },
};
```

then I apply it in pages/api/graphql.ts

```js
//...
import { applyMiddleware } from "graphql-middleware";
//...
const schemaWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(schema, checkStateMiddleware);

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ schema: schemaWithMiddleware });
//...
```